# From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array in angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

I have an array that looks like below:

```json
[
  { "name":"ABC", "group":"A" },
  { "name":"XYZ", "group":"A" },
  { "name":"KLP", "group":"A" },
  { "name":"AKG", "group":"B" },
  { "name":"DIS", "group":"B" },
  { "name":"FAC", "group":"B" },
  { "name":"TAM", "group":"B" },
  { "name":"NEW", "group":"C" },
  { "name":"UTL", "group":"C" },
  { "name":"WAC", "group":"C" }
]
```

How can I sort this by group in angular
I want result like below

```json
{
  "A":[ "ABC", "XYZ", "KLP" ],
  "B":[ "AKG", "DIS", "FAC", "TAM" ],
  "C":[ "NEW", "UTL", "WAC" ]
}
```

Please help me to do so
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
const sortedData: any = {};
for (const d of this.data) {
    sortedData[d.group] ? sortedData[d.group].push(d.name) : sortedData[d.group] = [d.name];
}
```

Comment: thannks. it is working